# Prevent segue from executing twice

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am on OSX, Xcode 8.2, not iOS.

I open a view with a storyboard segue (popover) on a button click, not programmatically.

While the popover is "popping up" if one clicks the triggering button fast the segue is called multiple times opening multiple popovers at the same place above each other.

I'd like to prevent the popover from being opened twice if a popover is already opened. What would be the best way to do that?

My current approach is to save the activation/opening in a BOOL in prepareForSegue and to check for its value in shouldPerformSegue. The variable then is resetted by the view itself (on closing via delegate)

But it doesn't feel clean so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing this task.

Comment: I don't know about macOS, but couldn't you check something like "`if( (self.presentedViewController)` or something like that, since you call a "presentPopover or soemthing"?

Answer (score 0):

remove performSegueWithIdentifier 
and use in prepareForSegue something like this;

```
let indexPath : NSIndexPath! = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

i don't know how write this in objective but in swift i'm sure you get the index selected if you use tableview if you have just buttons to show view 
it's very easy 
just go in storyboard and give differents names to each identifier after

right something a Switch Statement with the identifier in case

```
switch control expression {

case identifier 1:
    statements

case identifier 2:
    statements

case identifier 3:
    statements

}
or 

if identifier == "btn1"{
destinationForSegue : ControllerName1

}

if identifier == "btn2"{
destinationForSegue : ControllerName2

}

if identifier == "btn3"{
destinationForSegue : ControllerName3

}
```

Comment: Aah. You pointed out a typo. I'm using prepareForSegue. Accidentally wrote performSegueWithIdentifier which is wrong cause it's button triggered and not automatically. I edited my initial post. I'm already using it in the way you mentioned but that doesn't prevent multiple popovers on repeatedly hitting the button.

Comment: so if u use the switch this make once for click but using "if" this  can send multiples i guess

Comment: I have only ONE button - So I only have ONE segue. If you hit the button repeatingly the ONE segue gets called multiple times- each time creating a new popover. A switch therfore makes no sense. I want to prevent every popover after the first so only one opens. Hope this makes it more clear

Comment: ok this is easy to solve it just write cascade "if" figuring each popover something like this

Answer (score -2):

try this

if  (bad action1) {

message this no god try again

}

else{

do your staff 1
    if bad action2{

message this no god try again

```
}
else{
do your staff 2
     if bad action3{
     message this no god try again    

     }
     else{
     do your staff 3 or final staff

     }

}
```

}